# URL Redirected even though I am logged in - PHP / Session

Tags: php, session, redirect, cookies

I have an admin page (../index2.php) I  would like to log in as my home URL when I first open the browser.  You have to be logged in to view this page with username and password.  Obviously if I log out and close the browser, then reopen, it should redirect to the login page.  This is the top code of the index2.php page when it first opens:

```
<?php
      require_once ("../includes_kl/initialize.php"); // simply sets up database and other classes including session class
?>
<?php
    if(!$session->is_logged_in()) {
    redirect_to("/cms/login.php");
    }
?>
```

It will redirect to the login.php page, but that page does this:

```
require_once ("../../includes_kl/initialize.php");
if ($session->is_logged_in()) {// Skip login page if already logged in.
    redirect_to("index.php");
}
```

And because I am now logged in apparently (not sure when that happened), it goes to index.php.

I verify my cookiees are set when I open the browser.  And the cookies do this:

```
  private function check_login() {

    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && (isset($_COOKIE['username']))) {
        $_SESSION['user_id']= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];

    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->logged_in = true;
    } else {
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->logged_in = false;
    }
}

My session Constructor:

function __construct() {
      session_start();
      $this->check_login();
}
```

UPDATE: I added this code to echo varibles:

```
function __construct() {
      session_start();
      $this->check_login();
       if ($this->logged_in) {
        echo "Session User Success: " . $this->username;
        } else {
        echo "Session User Fail";
        }
}
```

It returns the "Session User Fail" When I first open the browser (I took off the redirect for testing purposes in the index2.php so I can see the results).

UPDATED 2:

I have tracked down issues as Cookiees NOT being set.

Here is where I set them:

```
public function login($user) {
    global $database;
    if ($user) {
        $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;
        setcookie('user_id', $this->user_id, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 14));
        setcookie('username', $this->username, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 14));
        $this->logged_in = true;
      }
}
```

Is this being done correct?  This is part of when the user is logging in.  I have verified in Chrome that the cookies are set.  Yet, in the check_login() method, it odes not find them in that first "if" statement.  The "isset" test fails.

Comment: can you echo your session variables to check if they hold any values when you logged in.

Comment: Well, I tried echoing when the index2.php first opens, and it shows the value ($session->username) is empty.  But I'm not sure this was the best place to test.  Perhaps inside the Session class would be better?

Comment: yes, you should echo it where it is initialize to check if it was given any values.

Comment: Check the updated code towards the bottom, it  looks like they are returning empty.

Comment: it seems your check_login isn't doing what's is supposed to do. why don't you try doing something like $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['var']; instead of the cookie, since it seems your cookie variable is empty. i'm not that familiar with cookies though since i prefer using sessions for this kind of checking.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  You got me on the right track.  I have determined the cookies are not being set by echoing out variables throughout the process.  I have updated the code again to show where I set the cookies. I am going to try to figure it out with this method. (sorry, I accidentally opened up chat)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, im sorry though that i could not be of more assistance in the cookie part, since i am not that familiar with that functionality. i would suggest using pure session though, but if you have something in mind with your cookie then do continue using it.

p.s i am not that sure this would work `$this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;`

would you try initializing them one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with help from another question.  It did have to do with Cookies.  I simply need to set the path and the domain in the setcookie() method.

setcookie('username', $this->username, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 14), **'/', 'domain.com'**);

My login.php (where the cookie was first set) was in a *different* folder level than my index2.php that the browser was opening up to.  So the cookie was *only* set for the folders in the 'domain.com/folder/HERE' level (this is where my login.php was:  domain.com/CMS/login.php).

On the other hand, I was opening up browser to domain/index2.php where the cookie was not set.  So it then sent you to the login.php page where the cookie WAS seen so it would pass the same test that it just field and redirect you to index.php where I was not logged in.  So that is why my browser was opening me up in index.php AND logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check several things.

You should check server response HTTP headers and look there for Set-Cookie header. If it is there, than it is not a problem with *setcookie* function. You will need to check client request HTTP headers and look for Cookie header there.

However, more possible that you have no Cookie header in your server response. It can happen for different reasons, but the most likely is because of "Headers already sent" warning. If you have display_errors = off in your config, then you can see this warning only in your log files. It means, that your server has started data (i.e. HTTP response body) transfer before login function was called and is not able to set any other headers. You can check it using *header* function. To do so you need to place this code to the very beginning of index2.php:

```
header('Start: OK');
```

and this code inside check_login function:

```
header('Check-Login: OK');
```

After that you need to check which headers you have in your response.

And one more thing. You should avoid constructions like that:

```
$_SESSION['user_id']= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
```

It's a real security gap. As far as I can change cookies at the client side, I can login with any user's credentials.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, I actually did figure it out and it had to do with something else.  The new answer is posted.  Thanks for the security tip though, I really need to get in better practice with that.